# Indexing one numpy array using another numpy array elements gives "TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars"

Tags: python, numpy

I have following code

Lets name rows of array `karr` as `s1,a,s2,r,t`:

```
>>> k = [[0.,0.,0.,-0.9,0.3],[0.,0.,1.,0.9,0.6]]
>>> import numpy as np
>>> karr = np.array(k)
>>> V = np.array([3,4])
```

I want to calculate `r+V[s2]` for each element `s1,a,s2,r,t` of array.
So, the output I want is `[-0.9+V[int(0.)],0.9+V[int(1.)]]=[-0.9+3,0.9+4]=[2.1,4.9]`. I tried following, but I got below error:

```
>>> karr[:,3] + V[int(karr[:,2])]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Changing `V[karr[:,2]` to `V[int(1.0)]` works (though this is not what I want):

```
>>> karr[:,3] + V[int(1.0)]
array([-0.9,  0.9])
```

How can I make `karr[:,3] + V[karr[:,2]]` work?

Comment: ```karr``` doesn't have ints

Comment: Sorry I missed `int()` there. Updated the question now. Trying with `int()` still gives same error.

Comment: Sorry, again, it gives different error which I originally intended to ask. In hurry I copy / pasted int-related error.

Comment: Where your code says `int(karr[:,2])`, what do you expect that to *mean*? What *exactly* should the result be?

Comment: Consider `[0.,0.,0.,-0.9,0.3]`. I want to calculate `r+V[s2]`. Here, `s2` is third `0.`. So I want to calculate `r+V[int(.0)]`. Here, `r` is `-0.9` and `V[int(.0)]=3`. So, I want this to result in -0.9+3=2.1 as also explained in the original question. So by `int(karr[:,2])`, I want to cast 2nd index element of current row to int.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Just realised that `int(karr[:,2])` fails with the error I specified but `karr[:,2].astype(int)` does not. Is it because `int(karr[:,2])` is non-numpy function, but is plain python function? And `astype()` is defined on `numpy.ndarray`.

Comment: Yep, you've got it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `karr[:,2]` is not integer, You could do

```
karr[:,3] + V[karr[:,2].astype(int)]

#array([2.1, 4.9])
```

---

```
karr[:,2].astype(int)
array([0, 1])
```

is not the same than

```
V[1]
4
```

Comment: Sorry I missed `int()` there. Updated the question now. Trying with `int()` still gives same error.

Comment: Sorry, again, it gives different error which I originally intended to ask. In hurry I copy / pasted int-related error.

Comment: the problem is that you are indexing with non-integer values. Then you have to make sure that the indexing of the addends is done with integer values. 
Try to run the second solution to the problem that I have post

Comment: Can you please reread the question. Its substantially changed now. The issue was not with ints, both the error and title of original question is changed. (Changing float to int as in second solution unacceptably changes 0.9 to 0. But anyway that was not the actual issue I was facing.)

Comment: Didnt get "is not the same than
`V[1]  
4`". Also realised that `int(karr[:,2])` fails with the error I specified but `karr[:,2].astype(int)` does not. Is it because `int(karr[:,2])` is non-numpy function, but is plain python function? And `astype()` is defined on `numpy.ndarray`.

Comment: `int ()` doesn't accept an instance of numpy.ndarray as an argument, so we need to use `.astype(int)`. If when indexing an array the result is another array then you cannot use int (). So if you use` karr[:, 2]` it returns an array so we need to use .astype (int), instead int, int(karr [0, 1]) does not give an error because `karr[0, 1]` is not an instance of numpy .ndarray